# Java Array Bulk Flush on Disk

Tags: java, arrays

I have two arrays (int and long) which contains millions of entries. Until now, I am doing it using DataOutputStream and using a long buffer thus disk I/O costs gets low (nio is also more or less same as I have huge buffer, so I/O access cost low) specifically, using

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc.txt"),1024*1024*100));

for(int i = 0 ; i < 220000000 ; i++){
    long l = longarray[i];
    dos.writeLong(l);
}
```

But it takes several seconds (more than 5 minutes) to do that. Actually, what I want to bulk flush (some sort of main memory to disk memory map). For that, I found a nice approach in [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bonachea/java/dist/doc/html/ti/io/BulkDataInputStream.html) and [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bonachea/java/dist/doc/html/ti/io/BulkDataOutputStream.html). However, can't understand how to use that in my javac. Can anybody help me about that or any other way to do that nicely ?

Comment: It really shouldn't take more than a few seconds. I would try reducing the buffer size to 32 KB.  Having buffers larger than this can actually be slower. You should eb able to write at least 40 to 400 MB/s depending on your hardware.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I modify my code. Is it have any issue ? But, it takes, 498 seconds.

Comment: Are you writing to a local filesystem (as opposed to a network one)?

Comment: What do you mean by "However, can't understand how to use that in my javac"? : just download archive, get Java files Ti/jni/BulkDataOutputStream.java and add it to classes you're compiling.

Comment: @aix, I am running it server with 16GB memory with 2.13 GhZ memory and java code writes it in it's local memory.

Comment: @ArtemOboturov, I have not found anywhere the archive.

Comment: @Arpssss [http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bonachea/java/](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bonachea/java/), click link with name "Java Bulk I/O Extensions, version 1.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine, 3.8 GHz i7 with an SSD

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc.txt"), 32 * 1024));

long start = System.nanoTime();
final int count = 220000000;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    long l = i;
    dos.writeLong(l);
}
dos.close();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to write %,d longs%n",
        time / 1e9, count);
```

prints

```
Took 11.706 seconds to write 220,000,000 longs
```

---

Using memory mapped files

```
final int count = 220000000;

final FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("abc.txt", "rw").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, count * 8);
mbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    long l = i;
    mbb.putLong(l);
}
channel.close();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to write %,d longs%n",
        time / 1e9, count);

// Only works on Sun/HotSpot/OpenJDK to deallocate buffer.
((DirectBuffer) mbb).cleaner().clean();

final FileChannel channel2 = new RandomAccessFile("abc.txt", "r").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb2 = channel2.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel2.size());
mbb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
assert mbb2.remaining() == count * 8;
long start2 = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    long l = mbb2.getLong();
    if (i != l)
        throw new AssertionError("Expected "+i+" but got "+l);
}
channel.close();
long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to read %,d longs%n",
        time2 / 1e9, count);

// Only works on Sun/HotSpot/OpenJDK to deallocate buffer.
((DirectBuffer) mbb2).cleaner().clean();
```

prints on my 3.8 GHz i7.

```
Took 0.568 seconds to write 220,000,000 longs
```

on a slower machine prints

```
Took 1.180 seconds to write 220,000,000 longs
Took 0.990 seconds to read 220,000,000 longs
```

---

> Is here any other way not to create that ? Because I have that array already on my main memory and I can't allocate more than 500 MB to do that?

This doesn't uses less than 1 KB of heap. If you look at how much memory is used before and after this call you will normally see no increase at all.

> Another thing, is this gives efficient loading also means MappedByteBuffer?

In my experience, using a memory mapped file is by far the fastest because you reduce the number of system calls and copies into memory.

> Because, in some article I found read(buffer) this gives better loading performance. (I check that one, really faster 220 million int array -float array read 5 seconds)

I would like to read that article because I have never seen that.

> Another issue: readLong gives error while reading from your code output file

Part of the performance in provement is storing the values in native byte order. writeLong/readLong always uses big endian format which is much slower on Intel/AMD systems which are little endian format natively.

You can make the byte order big-endian which will slow it down or you can use native ordering (DataInput/OutputStream only supports big endian)

Comment: thanks a lot again. Issue with it is, I have to allocate another same size array(2.64 GB, I have another int one, same size) with this command: map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, count * 8). Is here any other way not to create that ? Because I have that array already on my main memory and I can't allocate more than 500 MB to do that? Another thing, is this gives efficient loading also means MappedByteBuffer? Because, in some article I found read(buffer) this gives better loading performance. (I check that one, really faster 220 million int array -float array read 5 seconds).

Comment: Another issue: readLong gives error while reading from your code output file.

Comment: I replied to your comments as edits. BTW: If you only used the MappedByteBuffer instead of an int[] or long[] or double[] it wouldn't use much heap at all (and you wouldn't have to do anything to write the data to disk)

Comment: thanks. I found read(buf) gives nice performence from http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning. Another thing, can you kindly show, how to read by using MappedByteBuffer in an efficient way ?

Comment: Added an example of how to read sequential. Note: you can also access the data randomly so you can start/finish anywhere you like.

Answer (score 1):

> I am running it server with 16GB memory with 2.13 GhZ [CPU]

I doubt the problem has anything to do with your Java code.

Your file system appears to be extraordinarily slow (*at least* ten times slower than what one would expect from a local disk).

I would do two things:

1. Double check that you are actually writing to a local disk, and not to a network share. Bear in mind that in some environments home directories are NFS mounts.
2. Ask your sysadmins to take a look at the machine to find out why the disk is so slow. If I were in their shoes, I'd start by checking the logs and running some benchmarks (e.g. using [Bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/)).

Comment: thanks, I will check. It seems somewhere in the system has flaws. I have to ask. Thanks.